# How can I uninstall haguichi? /var/lib/dpkg/info/haguichi.postrm: glib-compile-schemas: not found

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall

When I try to uninstall haguichi, this happens:

```
Removing haguichi (1.3.3~ubuntu16.04.1) ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/haguichi.postrm: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/haguichi.postrm: glib-compile-schemas: not found
dpkg: error processing package haguichi (--remove): subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 haguichi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: How did you install `haguichi`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the missing component `libglib2.0-bin` which contains the `glib-compile-schemas` command.

Because haguichi is damaged, `apt-get` or `dpkg` tries to remove it every time you want to install or uninstall something and that ends in an error because the `libglib2.0-bin` is missing and haguichi's uninstaller depends on it.

The following solution worked for me and I hope will do the same for you:

I simply told `apt-get` to ignore haguichi during any install or uninstall process. Afterwards I installed the missing component and then told `apt-get` to uninstall haguichi.

Below are the commands I used:

```
sudo -s
echo haguichi hold | dpkg --set-selections
apt-get install libglib2.0-bin
apt-get remove haguichi
exit
```

**Note:** When you execute the command `apt-get install libglib2.0-bin` a haguichi error will appear at the end but regardless libglib has bin successfully installed.

I did this by using the command I found on [here on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29652/block-a-package-from-being-uninstalled-in-apt).